# How do I encrypt session data into a token to authorize subsequent web service calls?

Tags: .net, encryption, azure, wcf-security, acs

I have a web service that needs to be protected from unauthorized users. I need to expose a web service operation to Authorize a user, based on username and password. The response to the user validation request should contain a security token. That security token contains some embedded user properties that the client applicatino can use, but when encrypted, will also be used to authenticate subsequent web service operations. The unencrypted token looks something like this:

```
UID=444; DTE=2012-06-01T14:01:54.9571247Z; GID=1; WID=00:1C:B3:04:85:11; SID=lit3py55t21z5v55vlm25s55;
```

I can use a symmetric key algorithm as the key can be a shared secret between client and server (I control both). I have implemented the following [Rijndael example](http://www.obviex.com/samples/Encryption.aspx) using SHA1 and a key size of 256.

This code is [often quoted across the internet](https://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&q=%22Encrypts%20specified%20plaintext%20using%20Rijndael%20symmetric%20key%20algorithm%22), but [Microsoft themselves, state in relation to Rijndael](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndael%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> The **Rijndael** class is the predecessor of the [Aes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aes%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) algorithm. You should
>   use the [Aes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aes%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) algorithm instead of **Rijndael**. For more information, see
>   the entry [The Differences Between Rijndael and AES](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=200932) in the .NET
>   Security blog.

Are there any security concerns I should have? If so, how would you change the example code, or can anyone provide a better, more secure example?

Finally, as an alternative, I am considering using [Windows Azure Access Control Service](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/access-control/) to issue security tokens against my own identity provider, and using that token to get user account data as a separate call. Since the application is running in Azure, would this be a better implementation? Would anyone like to share their experience of using ACS for such an architecture?

BTW: The client application is iOS 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of building something yourself you could use the **FormsAuthentication.Encrypt** method. This method will encrypt and **sign** your FormsAuthenticationTicket (this 'ticket' can contain a username with additional information). By signing your ticket it also prevents tampering (this is based on the machine key).

The encrypted ticket is simply a string you could send to the mobile device. Then, for each other request you could simply send the token and decrypt it server side. That's it for the authentication part.

Now, if you want to send encrypted data to your client I suggest you simply transfer the data over HTTPS (the same applies to your token).

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.encrypt.aspx